# I wrote a Liferay module. How to make it configurable by administrators?

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

I have created a Liferay 7 module, and it works well.

**Problem**: In the Java source code I hard-coded something that administrators need to modify.

**Question**: What is the Liferay way to externalize settings? I don't mind if the server has to be restarted, but of course the ability to modify settings on a live running server (via Gogo Shell?) could be cool provided that these settings then survive server restarts.

*More specifically, I have a module for which I would like to be able to configure an API key that looks like `"3g9828hf928rf98"` and another module for which I would like to configure a list of allowed structures that looks like `"BASIC-WEB-CONTENT","EVENTS","INVENTORY"`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay is utilizing the standard OSGi configuration. It's quite a task documenting it here, but it's well laid out [in the documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/making-your-applications-configurable).

In short:

```
@Meta.OCD(id = "com.foo.bar.MyAppConfiguration")
public interface MyAppConfiguration {

    @Meta.AD(
        deflt = "blue",
        required = false
    )
    public String favoriteColor();

    @Meta.AD(
       deflt = "red|green|blue",
       required = false
    )
    public String[] validLanguages();

    @Meta.AD(required = false)
    public int itemsPerPage();

}
```

`OCD` stands for ObjectClassDefinition. It ties this configuration class/object to the configurable object through the id/pid.

`AD` is for AttributeDefinition and provides some hints for the configuration interface, which is auto-generated with the help of this meta type.

And when you don't like the appearance of the autogenerated UI, you "only" have to add localization keys for the labels that you see on screen (standard Liferay translation).

You'll find a lot more details on OSGi configuration for example on [enroute](http://enroute.osgi.org), though the examples I found are always a bit more complex than just going after the configuration.